# How Do I / Can I Upgrade Java from Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm brand new to JAva/Eclipse/Android but gearing up! I've got everything installed and working but want to know how Java is upgraded. Can it be done through Eclipse? I noticed that the JDK install wants to create a new folder each time based on its version. I'll do whatever is needed but appreciate your input to get me started.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just install JDK the usual way. The new folder is not a problem. Once you've installed the JDK, you can instruct Eclipse to use it by *Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs*. You can add or edit the installed JREs over there. If you choose *Edit*, you just have to change the home directory and the name.

Comment: Got it! Thanks BalusC - this was what I was thinking but wanted to be totally sure. I've been a developer for years but not in Java at all. I want to dive in deep and enjoy! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There's no upgrade for Java, in fact, you always install a new version of Java on your system and and free to decide whether do uninstall the previous one.

The eclipse IDE will run with the systems default java runtime. And it doesn't need a JDK, it has it's own compiler.

Comment: Thanks! How would I know what the system's using as the default JRE? And - I see that the JDK comes with a JRE too (poking around in the folders and before downloading it was obvious) so is there a need to have both?!? I would think not...but being "green" I want to learn about the JDK's and JRE's this before I start getting busy coding. Thanks again!!! Greataly appreciated!- Freddo